live server in VS code is not working properly
I have installed a live server on VS Code.
But while I was trying to open the live server using right-click, I didn't find (open with live server).
Also, when I click GO LIVE, it opens a page showing all files in the directory, as shown below.
How I can solve this issue???
enter image description here
I tried to uninstall vs code many times.

did you install the PHP server in visual studio code ?
I suggest you read this solution given in this other thread !
